# Fetch some string from a standard text using Pattern in android

Tags: java, android

Im developing an android APP which has a Broadcast-Receiver based on SMS incoming message.

I want to track every message from specific senderNumber, and do some stuff with that SMS, for example, retrieve some data from every message.

The messsage body I want to analyse is this:

> "Usted ha recibido **5.0** CUC del numero **55391393**.Saldo principal
>   **1565.0** CUC, linea activa hasta 2019-02-10, vence 2019-03-12"

I want to extract with Pattern class, the values marked in bold. But I'm really new in Regular Expressions. Some help?

This is my actual code:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                assert pdusObj != null;
                for (Object aPdusObj : pdusObj) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aPdusObj);
                    String senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    /*
                    String body = currentMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String address = currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    */

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    //Save to DB
                    if (senderNum.equals("Cubacel")) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //Parse this SMS with Regular Expresions


                    } else {
                        //Search for transferred numbers pending
                    }

                } // end for loop

            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample working code with JS, but I have NO idea how to implement in Java
https://regexr.com/3mgq2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it, please tell me if there is a better way:

```
public String[] parseTransfer(String cubacelMessage) {

        String[] data = new String[2];

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Usted ha recibido (\\d+\\.\\d+) CUC del numero (\\d+).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cubacelMessage);

        matcher.find();

        data[1] = matcher.group(1);
        data[2] = matcher.group(2);

        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re2="(5\\.0)";   // Float 1
    String re3=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re4="(55391393)";    // Number 1
    String re5=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re6="(1565\\.0)";    // Float 2

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Try this :)

Comment: The text may vary, I want the Float, and number, not the specific number itself. Example: "Usted ha recibido 2.30 CUC del numero 54663598.Saldo principal 756.0 CUC, linea activa hasta 2019-02-10, vence 2019-03-12"

Comment: Thanks anyway, the answer is near.

Comment: Yes just replace the string in re4 with a different one. This is just an example. You have to work out the rest.